# What is the advantage of strlmove vs strmove in C?

Tags: c

To trim the leading spaces we are using strmove. But we were advised to use strlmove instead of strmove. I have read and used strlcpy and strlcat. Whether strlmove does the similar functionality and what all are its advantages?

Edit 1: Thank you Mike B and Chris Young. This is how we use strlcpy.

```
size_t strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    strncpy(dst, src, size - 1);
    dst[size - 1] = '\0';
    return(strlen(src));
}
```

So I was just thinking of using strlmove() also  in the same way. I want to confirm whether any specifications is defined regarding the implementation of strlmove(). I know this is one of the best place i can ask.

Edit 2: strlmove() is implemented the same way as strlcpy() and strlcat() using memmove().

```
size_t strlmove(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    //Error if the size is 0
    //If src length is greater than size; 
    //   memmove(dst, src, size-1) and dst[size] = \0;
    //Otherwise
    //   memmove(dst, src, length(src));
    return source len;
}
```

Appreciate the help and support provided.

Thanks,
Mathew Liju

Comment: This is the only place that Google finds a reference to strlmove(); it knows more about strmove().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Chris Young mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260962/what-is-the-advantage-of-strlmove-vs-strmove-in-c#260972), these routines are not standard (or as far as I known in wide, common use) so I can't be 100% certain with more specifics, but:

Typically the `strl()` variations of `str()` routines take an additional parameter that indicates the size of the destination buffer.  The routine guarantees that it will not write data past the end of the buffer (since it knows the size).  Usually `strl()` functions will also guarantee that they will place a terminating null character at the end of the string or at the end of the buffer (potentially truncating any string created there) so that you are also guaranteed to have a terminated string that will be generally OK to pass to other `str()` functions.  Note that if the length of the buffer is specified as 0 (zero) the function will *not* place a terminating null character (as there's no room in the buffer for anything).

In my opinion, it's nearly always better to use a `strl()` (or `strn()`) function in preference to the corresponding `str()` routine to prevent buffer overruns.

Answer (score 4):

strmove, strlmove, strlcpy, strlcat are all **not** standard C functions, so I can't comment on what they do without knowing which specific non-standard library you're using. Standard C provides strcpy, strcat, strncat, strncpy, memmove, memcpy, etc.

It makes sense to use strncpy over strcpy for safety if you don't know the source string will fit inside the destination buffer. However, strncpy has a major performance issue in that it **always** writes the amount of bytes specified for the size. That is:

```
char buf[4096];
strncpy(buf, "Hello", sizeof buf);
```

will write 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and fill the remaining 4091 bytes of buf with '\0'. Another thing to be aware of with strncpy is that it will not null-terminate the string if the size parameter is smaller than the source string length plus its null. For example:

```
char buf[5];
strncpy(buf, "Hello", sizeof buf);
```

will write 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' into buf and it will not be null-terminated.

Answer (score 1):

Quick Google search reveals that the only mentions of strlmove function  is in stackoverflow :). So it's probably not very common function.
But if we assume that this function is close by nature to [strlcpy](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcpy/), this function is differ from [strmove](http://sancho.ccd.uniroma2.it/cgi-bin/man/man2html?strmove+3) by using size parameter to move limited amount of bytes and **make the destination string NULL terminated**.

Comment: Yes Ilya that could be the last option to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is one big difference between strncpy and strlcpy at least in the version of Theo de Raadt, that you missed in your implementation. If the length of the given string is less than the buffer size, then strncpy pads the rest of the buffer with null bytes. This might be only a minor difference in many cases, but since many c programmer tend to use extra large buffers to be on the safe site, it can make a difference.

```
strncpy(buffer, "bla", 1024);
```

will write 1021 '\0' into the buffer although one would be enough. strlcpy only writes one '\0'.

Comment: Wow ... Good find. We missed that in our implementation. I have corrected it. Thanks for finding it out.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris said, the functions you are using currently are non-std. ... even worse is that they are still highly inefficient and are still prone to errors. You chould be able to easily create a couple of APIs that use memcpy/memmove and take (char *)s which will work everywhere and likely be faster than the non-std. varients you are currently using.

However if you want someone else to do the heavy lifting, and get safety/usability for free, you could look at something like [ustr](http://www.and.org/ustr) ... which is meant to be easy to integrate, is std. C, safe, fast, and can deal with constant/automatic/utf8/dynamic strings. There are also other options.